# redis LRANGE and SRANDMEMBER Together

Tags: redis

i have some records in redis

```
         1) "one"
         2) "two"
         3) "three"
         4) "four"
         5) "five"
         6) "six"
         7) "seven"
         8) "eight"
         9) "nine"
        10) "ten"
        11) "eleven"
        12) "twelve"
        13) "thirteen"
        14) "fourteen"
        15) "fifteen"
        16) "sixteen"
        17) "seventeen"
        18) "eighteen"
        19) "nineteen"
```

i have to get first 10 values from the list

```
        LRANGE keyname 1 10
```

and i have to get last 10 values from the list

```
       LRANGE keyname (n-10) n
```

or say get middle 10 values from the list

```
      LRANGE keyname (n/2) (n/2)+10
```

and i have to get random 10 values from this list

```
      SRANDMEMBER keyname 10
```

so in order to performance all this operation
which datatype should i use in redis to achieve this ?

i am currently doing this

```
      LRANGE keyname randomNumber randomNumber+10
```

but it not completely random

EDITED

I want to perform both operation on by data in redis
get range of data(like LRANGE) and get random data(like SRANDMEMBER)?

Comment: You're mixing Redis' Lists (LRANGE) and Sets (SRANDMEMBER) - perhaps if you edit your question and explain what you're trying to achieve you'll get proper answers :)

Comment: yes i want to get random 10 values from the list (something like SRANDMEMBER performed on sets)

Comment: The problem with that is that doing random access on a List is very inefficient as each read is basically O(N). It boils down to using the right data structure for the job - if you need order, use a List, if you need quick (O(logN)), random reads use a Set.

Comment: so can do both random and sequential access on redis using any other datatype